# what's difference between maven tomcat plugin and tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

when i use maven tomcat plugin to integrate maven profile and spring profile,but it failed: cant use placeholder in the web.xml,my maven install command is :

```
clean install org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.2:run --define maven.tomcat.port=8080 --define maven.tomcat.path=/
```

when i change to use tomcat directly,it worked.

web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>${env}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

pom.xml:

```
     <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
           <configuration>
               <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
               <!-- activate spring profile -->
               <webResources>
                   <resource>
                       <filtering>true</filtering>
                       <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                       <includes>
                           <include>**/web.xml</include>
                       </includes>
                   </resource>
               </webResources>
               <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
               <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
```

Comment: Where is "env" defined? Would it suffice to do it differently and supply -Dspring.profiles.active=local in your startup command?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is `<webXml>` a valid tag? Shouldn't it be: `<tomcatWebXml>`?